# How to disable one particular Spring AOP Aspect?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, aop

I want to disable AOP for a particular Aspect (class level). Please note that I do not want to disable AOP across the application but for a particular aspect.
Reason- when I enable aspect, the server takes longer to start as well as it runs slow.

Comment: Just comment out the `@Component` annotation in that @Aspect  class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we enable or disable Aspect based on value of any flag or through configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406192/can-we-enable-or-disable-aspect-based-on-value-of-any-flag-or-through-configurat)

Answer (score 2):

Can you move that particular class to some other package where AOP Point-cut is not configured?
Basically using point-cut you can easily avoid unwanted packages. 
you can also use [RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/support/RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor.html)

Comment: I want it to be pluggable or I want to use some property flag to enable or disable it.

Comment: the slowness that you face i think because of the code you execute using AOP, you can turn off the complete code block by some custom property, unfortunately i am not aware of any such property to control a specific point-cut, let me know if you find such thing.